# ByteBuffer Missing Data When decoded As string

Tags: java, string, byte, bytebuffer

I'm reading and writing to a ByteBuffer

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder;

public class Solution{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    final CharsetEncoder messageEncoder = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1").newEncoder();
    String message = "TRANSACTION IGNORED";
    String carrierName= "CARR00AB";
    int messageLength = message.length()+carrierName.length()+8;


    System.out.println(" --------Fill data---------");
    ByteBuffer messageBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
    messageBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    messageBuffer.putInt(messageLength);
    messageBuffer.put(messageEncoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(carrierName)));
    messageBuffer.put(messageEncoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(message)));
    messageBuffer.put((byte) 0x2b);
    messageBuffer.flip();

    System.out.println("------------Extract Data Approach 1--------");

    CharsetDecoder messageDecoder = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1").newDecoder();
    int lengthField = messageBuffer.getInt();
    System.out.println("lengthField="+lengthField);
    int responseLength = lengthField - 12;
    System.out.println("responseLength="+responseLength);
    String messageDecoded= messageDecoder.decode(messageBuffer).toString();
    System.out.println("messageDecoded="+messageDecoded);
    String decodedCarrier = messageDecoded.substring(0, carrierName.length());
    System.out.println("decodedCarrier="+ decodedCarrier);
    String decodedBody = messageDecoded.substring(carrierName.length(), messageDecoded.length() - 1);
    System.out.println("decodedBody="+decodedBody);

    Assertions.assertThat(messageLength).isEqualTo(lengthField);
    Assertions.assertThat(decodedBody).isEqualTo(message);
    Assertions.assertThat(decodedBody).isEqualTo(message);

    ByteBuffer messageBuffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
    messageBuffer2.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    messageBuffer2.putInt(messageLength);
    messageBuffer2.put(messageEncoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(carrierName)));
    messageBuffer2.put(messageEncoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(message)));
    messageBuffer2.put((byte) 0x2b);
    messageBuffer2.flip();

    System.out.println("---------Extract Data Approach 2--------");

    byte [] data = new byte[messageBuffer2.limit()];
    messageBuffer2.get(data);
    String dataString =new String(data, "ISO-8859-1");
    System.out.println(dataString);

}
}
```

It works fine but then I thought to refactor it, Please see approach 2 in above code

```
    byte [] data = new byte[messageBuffer.limit()];
    messageBuffer.get(data);
    String dataString =new String(data, "ISO-8859-1");
    System.out.println(dataString);

 Output=     #CARR00ABTRANSACTION IGNORED+
```

Could you guys help me with explanation

1. why the integer is got missing in second approach while decoding ???
2. Is there any way to extract the integer in second approach??

Comment: Without reading the question, Have you provided an encoding?

Comment: yes , Please see my code in question

Comment: Okay, I will compile the code my side and verify the issue if someone else hasn't already before me.

Comment: Where did you place your last code? Can you provide working example?

Comment: see updates , please remove Assertions before executing code

Comment: The output looks fine to me, The integer isn't missing.

Comment: so you mean the print statement contians 35 'System.out.println(dataString);' ??

Comment: I see `33` on both... this is first output `messageDecoded=CARR0033TRANSACTION IGNORED+` and this is the second output `#CARR0033TRANSACTION IGNORED+` only thing that changed is there is `#`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185210/discussion-between-edwin-and-samzsakerz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so you are trying to read an `int` from the Buffer which takes up `4 bits` and then trying to get the whole data after reading `4 bits`

What I have done is call `messageBuffer2.clear();` after reading the int to resolve this issue. here is the full code

```
System.out.println(messageBuffer2.getInt());
byte[] data = new byte[messageBuffer2.limit()];
messageBuffer2.clear();
messageBuffer2.get(data);
String dataString = new String(data, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
System.out.println(dataString);
```

Output is:

```
35
   #CARR0033TRANSACTION IGNORED+
```

Edit: So basically when you are calling `clear` it resets various variables and it also resets the position it's getting from and thats how it fixes it.

Comment: Can you please explain how(logic behind) calling 'clear' fix this issue ??